# How can I force a page refresh when navigating to a page using forward/back?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, refresh, prototypejs

I have a page in which I add items to a database via AJAX calls and display the results below where they are added. The problem is when the user uses the forward/back button to navigate to the page it shows the items in the database which were originally shown on the first page load, not the new items which have been added. I've set all the appropriate meta tags to no cache but nothing seems to help. Does anyone know of the best way to force the page to refresh so an old version is never displayed. I'm using classic ASP and prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

You need "history management". Check out [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/).